# AWS Lambda Function: Cannot find package imported

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, import, require, aws-lambda-layers

I added the `knex` module (for example) to my function lambda (Node.js 14.x) from a lambda layer.
When I deploy my function in AWS Lambda and I use `require` in my lambda function works but with `import` not works.

**Note:** Locally works with `require` and `import` with modules installeds in `node_modules` in my lambda function.

### require (It works)

**index.js**

```
const knex = require('knex')(myConfig);
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-function",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

### import (Not works)

**index.js**

```
import knexModule from 'knex';

const {knex} = knexModule;
const db = knex(configKnex);
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-function",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

**Error**

```
Response
{
  "errorType": "Error",
  "errorMessage": "Cannot find package 'knex' imported from /var/task/index.js\nDid you mean to import knex/knex.js?",
  "trace": [
    "Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'knex' imported from /var/task/index.js",
    "Did you mean to import knex/knex.js?",
    "    at new NodeError (internal/errors.js:322:7)",
    "    at packageResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:732:9)",
    "    at moduleResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:773:18)",
    "    at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:887:11)",
    "    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:89:40)",
    "    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:242:28)",
    "    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:76:40)",
    "    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:75:36)",
    "    at process.runNextTicks [as _tickCallback] (internal/process/task_queues.js:60:5)",
    "    at /var/runtime/deasync.js:23:15"
  ]
}
```

How can I use `import` in AWS Lambda?

My layer downloaded from AWS Lambda looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Does [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-import-module-error-nodejs/) help?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara I followed the instructions but without success. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is because Lambda layers do not support ES modules yet, there are workarounds, however:

- Symlink the `node_modules` folder in your layer to `node_modules` in your Lambda function (https://github.com/vibe/aws-esm-modules-layer-support)
- Dynamic imports: https://github.com/coderbyheart/aws-lambda-esm-with-layer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).